# There is requirement to execute the gcloud commands inside workflow to check whether the cloud run job execution in process or not

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to run to gcloud commands inside cloud workflow to check whether the cloud run job execution in progress or not.
I need to run below commands

To find the latest created execution for a job

gcloud run jobs describe JOB_NAME --region REGION --format="value(status.latestCreatedExecution.name)"

To check that job completion time

gcloud run jobs executions describe LAST_CREATED_EXECUTION_FOR_JOB --region REGION --format="value(status.completionTime)"